# How do I finetune subpixel font anti-aliasing?

Tags: fonts, xfce

After a recent tour through Gnome3, KDE and Unity my font anti-aliasing in XFCE4 has changed in a subtle way (not sure if it was any of the DEs that changed the setting or any of the dependencies that got install when installing the DEs):

[image: Supixel Anti-Aliasing]

The font, Verdana 8, looks almost exactly the same, except in the old one subpixels where used to make the lines a little wider in the new one they are just one-pixel.

Which setting does cause this effect and how can I set it back? It's neither the hinting nor the subpixel ordering, which are the only settings reachable from XFCE4.

Edit: When I create a new account without any existing configuration I get the old subpixel rendering back.

Comment: How did you make that picture of the new an old display?

Comment: I had an old screenshot floating around with the old setting (which is why there are JPEG artifacts in the old part). The final image got assembled in Gimp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between the two font rendering was caused by the [LCD Filter](http://spasche.net/files/lcdfiltering/) setting. XFCE4 stores that setting in:

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml
```

To fix my problem I deleted the whole `<property name="Xft" type="empty">` section (might require to logout of XFCE4 to avoid getting the changes overwritten).

Doing a:

```
xfconf-query -v -c xsettings -p /Xft/Lcdfilter -s lcddefault
```

will also work (changes will only take effect after restarting XFCE4).